# Phone in Boot Loop & Need to Recover Data

Tags: backup, data-recovery, lg-g4

My LG G4 is stuck in boot loop and I need to recover the data. I thought that Andriod would have a system similar to Apple's icloud backup, but it doesn't seem they do (I thought this is what 'Sync' did).

Please could one of you guys point me in the direction of how I can recover my contacts & photos. Is there an online account that i'm not aware of or can I plug it into my Mac using special software?

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I think you could solve the bootloop and get the whole phone back tell me how it entered bootloop I can help you recover it

Comment: Help on getting out of a boot-loop can be found e.g. in our [boot-loop tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/boot-loop/info). For data recovery, there's a similar page with our [data-recovery tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/data-recovery/info). For more specific help, we'd need some more details: what did you do last before the issue came up that potentially contributed to it (install something, playing with root-powers)? Is the device rooted? Do you have a custom recovery installed?

Answer (score 0):

You can access your data trough TWRP. In case you don't have that installed, try re-flashing your current rom via fastboot or stock recovery.